# Audacity error importing .m4a file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, windows-11, audacity

Getting this error :

[image: Err msg frm audacity]

I have `ffmpeg` already installed on my system and also `environment part` has been set.

When searched on internet it was showing to install `ffmpeg` but I have `ffmpeg` installed on my system.
I don't want to convert the `.m4a` file to `.wav` or `.aiff` and use it.

How to fix the `.m4a` file importing error in audacity.

Comment: Do you have the ffmpeg **executable** installed, or have you actually installed the **library** it is asking for? If you have one it does not automatically mean the other is available.

Comment: Audacity also [appears you to need to manually point it to the library in the settings](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/installing_ffmpeg_for_windows.html) per this image: https://manual.audacityteam.org/m/images/b/b3/preferences_libraries_not_found_w10_lame_built_in.png so have you done that?

Comment: C:\Users\devpa>where ffmpeg
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\ffmpeg.exe

Comment: .exe is not a library. It likely wants a .dll file. My original comment still stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install the ffmpeg **library**, according to the instructions that you can find in the menu "Edit > Preferences > Libraries".  This is probably explained if you click on the question mark of the dialog box you have copied here.